# JWTBearer error on calling authorized method

Tags: c#, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, jwt

I am developing mobile REST API for small native mobile application. 
My trouble is JWT in assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer, Version=3.0.2.0

My settings in startup.cs method ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddJwtBearer(CommonHelper.MobileApiConstant.AuthSchemaName, options =>
                {
                    options.SaveToken = true;
                    options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        IssuerSigningKey =
                            new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                                CommonHelper.MobileApiConstant.GetSymmetricSecurityKeyByteArray(_customerCodeConfiguration.CustomerCode)),
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
                        ValidateIssuer = false,
                        ValidateAudience = false,
                    };
                });
```

My API controller is:

```
[Route(CommonHelper.MobileApiConstant.RouteName + "/[controller]/[action]")]
    [ApiController]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = CommonHelper.MobileApiConstant.AuthSchemaName)]
    [ApiVersion("1")]
    public class AuthenticationController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ResultModel<IMobileCrmUser>), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Authenticate([NotNull] string userName, [NotNull] string password)
        {
            if (!IsOk) // some usless logic 
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }

            JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            byte[] key = CommonHelper.MobileApiConstant.GetSymmetricSecurityKeyByteArray("My private string");

            SecurityTokenDescriptor tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(14),
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
            };
            SecurityToken token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

            return Ok(tokenHandler.WriteToken(token));
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
        public IActionResult TestMethodGet(string test)
        {
            if (test == nameof(test))
                return Ok("succes");
            else
                return BadRequest("bad");
        }
    }
```

When I call method Authenticate (Allow anonymous) all is ok:

```
curl -X GET "https://localhost:5001/MobileApi/Authentication/Authenticate?userName=mail%40mail.cz&password=password" -H "accept: text/plain" -H "x-api-version: 1"
```

Token is returned. Then i want to call TestMethodGet method the request is:

```
curl -X GET "https://localhost:5001/MobileApi/Authentication/TestMethodGet?test=test" -H "accept: text/plain" -H "x-api-version: 1" -H "Authorization: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6ImR2ZXNlbHlAY2VudHJ1bS5jeiIsIm5hbWVpZCI6IjIiLCJyb2xlIjpbIkFkbWluIiwiQnVzaW5lc3MiXSwibmJmIjoxNTg3MDMxOTAwLCJleHAiOjE1ODgyNDE1MDAsImlhdCI6MTU4NzAzMTkwMH0.rb_0nxWqedmruaBiaivd8ZrQBBi9SNcgsEQlqrOxhAo"
```

Response is:

```
content-length: 0 
 date: Thu, 16 Apr 2020 10:13:51 GMT 
 server: Kestrel 
 status: 401 
 www-authenticate: Bearer
```

I don't know where the error is and why the server doesn't write me more information. The API call is made through Swagger.

I tried to set options.IncludeErrorDetails = true; but with the same result.

Thank you for your help

Comment: change the header to `Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOi...`

Comment: curl -X GET "https://localhost:5001/MMobileApi/Authentication/TestMethodGet?test=test" -H "accept: text/plain" -H "x-api-version: 1" -H "Authorization Bearer: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6ImR2ZXNlbHlAY2VudHJ1bS5jeiIsIm5hbWVpZCI6IjIiLCJyb2xlIjpbIkFkbWluIiwiQnVzaW5lc3MiXSwibmJmIjoxNTg3MDI5NDkwLCJleHAiOjE1ODc2MzQyOTAsImlhdCI6MTU4NzAyOTQ5MH0.WJNv3k2vUZNOg6Wvjhg56et2KyX9aJ2Np4l83okK0lU"

this throw me this error: TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Invalid name

Comment: no idea what the error means, but there's a mistake in your header: the word 'Bearer' should  be after the ':', not before!

Comment: Ok... it helps... is there any way to avoid having a 'bearer' there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the word `Bearer` to the `Authorization` header:

```
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOi..
```

Then it should work.

---

In the response

```
content-length: 0 
date: Thu, 16 Apr 2020 10:13:51 GMT 
server: Kestrel 
status: 401 
www-authenticate: Bearer
```

you see not only the status, 401 in this case, but also the response header

```
www-authenticate: Bearer
```

which, according to [RFC1945](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-10.16)
tells you which scheme to use:

> The field value consists of at
> least one challenge that indicates the authentication scheme(s) and
> parameters applicable to the Request-URI.

So, it's the `Bearer` scheme in this case.

`Bearer` is the [standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-6.1.1) scheme for implementations of the OAuth2.0 authorization protocol.

See also [this Q/A](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/108662/why-is-bearer-required-before-the-token-in-authorization-header-in-a-http-re).